# Spring Integration Kafka Consumer Listener not Receiving messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

According to the documentation provided [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html), I am trying on a POC to get messages into a listener as mentioned in the [same documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html). Below is how I have written the configuration.

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    public static final String TEST_TOPIC_ID = "record-stream";

    @Value("${kafka.topic:" + TEST_TOPIC_ID + "}")
    private String topic;

    @Value("${kafka.address:localhost:9092}")
    private String brokerAddress;


    /*
      @Bean public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> adapter(
      KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
      KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String>
      kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter = new
      KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>( container, ListenerMode.record);
      kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(received()); return
      kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter; }
      
      @Bean public QueueChannel received() { return new QueueChannel(); }
     */

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(30000);
        return factory;
    }

    /*
     * @Bean public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container()
     * throws Exception { ContainerProperties properties = new
     * ContainerProperties(this.topic); // set more properties return new
     * KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory(), properties); }
     */

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddress);
        // props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "mygroup");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); // earliest
                                                                        // smallest
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
}
```

and Listener is as below:

```java
@Service
public class Listener {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Listener.class);

    @KafkaListener(topicPattern = KafkaConsumerConfig.TEST_TOPIC_ID, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void process(String message/* , Acknowledgment ack */) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Record record = gson.fromJson(message, Record.class);

        log.info(record.getId() + " " + record.getName());
        // ack.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

Even though I am producing messages to the same topic and this consumer is working on the same topic, Listener is not executing.

I am running Kafka 0.10.0.1, and here is my current pom. This consumer is working as a spring boot web application unlike many command line samples.

```xml
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I have spent a good amount of time to figure out why this listener is not getting hit when the topic has messages, what is it I am doing wrong.

I know that I can receive the messages using a channel (I have commented configuration part of that out in the code), but here the concurrency is handle clean.

Is this kind of implementation is possible with a async message consumption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add `@EnableKafka` alongside with the `@Configuration`.

Will [add](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/189) some description soon.

Meanwhile:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
```

Comment: I thought  EnableIntegration is taking care of that, in my Producer, I do not have EnableKafka. Let me try this and come back to you

Comment: `@EnableIntegration` is for Spring Integration, but we talk here about Spring Kafka. They are fully different independent projects. Look `@KafkaListener` is outside of Spring Integration Kafka. Like remember there are `@EnableJms`, `@EnableRabbit` and many other `@Enable...`. The only `@EnableIntegration` can't care about all of them. It isn't its responsibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight, your's worked like a charm. Will keep this in mind.